# can't launch my telegram bot on heroku server

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot

I'm trying to launch my bot using heroku but it doesn't and in logs it says 'no web processes running'.
Here is what I have in my git repo:
1. venv folder
2. Procfile:
    `web: gunicorn main:server`
3. main.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
token = 'token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
server = Flask(__name__)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hey(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hey')
@server.route('/' + token, methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "!", 200
@server.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url='url' + token)
    return "!", 200
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.debug = True
    server.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

4. `__init__.py` - empty file
5. requirements.txt
   According to what I've read in several tutorials, this should work. However, it doesn't. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I toggled this switch in heroku app resources settings.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofLNo.png)